# Laravel 5.2 - Login with only Email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, facebook-login

I am trying to create a [Social Login](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_login) with [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2).

I am getting **user-email**, so I need to log-in with **only that email**.

So, what I have done is-

```
Auth::attempt(
                [
                    'email' => $user->email
                ]);
```

But I am getting this error-

```
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112:
Undefined index: password
```

More detail-

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have solved it like this-

```
//Get the user
$user = User::where('email', '=', $user->email)->first();
//Now log in the user if exists
if ($user != null)
{
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

And it is working now :).

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that you've already answered your own question, but here's my response anyway.

It's worth noting that a password is required for a reason. By default, Laravel expects there to be a password, otherwise it's just insecure.

Rather than writing your way around the default auth implementation, why not use the Laravel package Socialite, a package made and maintained by Laravel (read: Taylor). It's quite literally part of Laravel, otherwise you're just reinventing the wheel.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: Hi @ollieread, appriatiate your help, but I am already using that. And, I need this part to implement auth after getting email from https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you should be using is:

`Auth::login($user);`

instead of:

`Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email]);`

In order to manually authenticate a user.

Comment: Bro, appreciate your help, but my problem is not this. I already solved this. Thanks

Comment: I know it's an old question, but that is great. thanks